# Simple mail server for web application

Tags: linux, email

I have a web application that needs to send outgoing mail. Instead of connecting directly to the SMTP server (I'm using AuthSMTP), I'd like to setup a local mail server. This is to reduce the time the web application has to wait to send the email, and to automatically store and retry the mail of the AuthSMTP server is down.

What mail server will be simple to setup and manage? All it needs to do is relay all mail from localhost to a specific server. I'd also like to be able to monitor the server, to see when some messages cannot be delivered.

I have some experience with Apache James, and I'm trying out Postfix currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current Linux web servers are Debian based, and in the one case I wanted the server to be able to send mail I just stuck with the default `exim4-daemon-light` package (http://packages.debian.org/lenny/exim4-daemon-light) which required very little extra configuration. It keeps logs that you should be able to parse with standard tools to monitor for failed delivery at the level of the initial SMTP connection. To be notified of errors that happen after that point you need to make sure the messages go out with valid `from` and `reply-to` headers so the receiving mailer knows where to send bounce messages (this last point is the same what-ever MTA you chose).

Comment: I'm sticking to postfix for now, but this seems like a good alternative.

Comment: For the simple jb of just sending mail from a local process like a scrip running under Apache, just about any MTA will do so what you are familiar with makes a diffrence. Just make sure that you correctly configure what-ever you use such that is doesn't act as an open relay.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a daemon running , and just a sendmail replacement, try ssmtp [http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSMTP

Easy config & no daemon running. I didn't remember, but it saves a log somewhere, so you can check for problems.

Another options would be nullmailer  or putmail.

I thought the tree works as sendmail replacements, so you can change your "/usr/lib/sendmail" for one of these), or you can configure apache/php to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this topic while trying to setup my own mail relay for my small homepage that has a contact form. I spent days trying to get postfix running and wanted to share the word that there is a much simpler solution for Linux (I use Debian on my server).

> What mail server will be simple to setup and manage?

As you mentioned there is [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), which is rather annoying to configure and debug. I personally prefer [OpenSMTPD](https://www.opensmtpd.org/), which has a much simpler to understand configuration and hence is perfect for your use case.

> All it needs to do is relay all mail from localhost to a specific server.

This functionality is referred to as a "mail relay" and is common for most web applications that want to relay mails to google or similar large email providers to be delivered to the final recipient.

> I'd also like to be able to monitor the server, to see when some messages cannot be delivered.

I would recommend you to configure your monitoring system to monitor the number of emails in the mail queue. If it is more than zero for a period of like 10 minutes, there is most likely a problem. For OpenSMTPD this works like follows in BASH - your monitoring system of choice most likely has a OpenSMTPD plugin.

```
root@webserver:~# smtpctl show queue | wc -l
0
```

> I have some experience with Apache James, and I'm trying out Postfix currently.

I have spend way to much time in postfix and would recommend you not use it, unless you configure a complex email server with in- and outgoing email accounts for 500 users or more.

OpenSMTPD can do this with two config files. After reading many blog and forum posts, a nice guy in IRC recommended me [this excellent blogpost](https://www.blunix.com/blog/secure-smtp-email-relay-on-debian-and-ubuntu-with-opensmtpd-instead-of-postfix.html), where I could copy paste everything and got my mail relay running in just a couple of minutes. All you need are the following config files and to install the package:

`apt install opensmtpd`

Then the configs, first `/etc/smtpd.conf`:

```
table relay_secrets file:/etc/smtpd/tables/relay_secrets

listen on lo port 25 mask-src hostname example.com

listen on socket mask-src

action "relay_monitoring"     relay tls host smtp://monitoring@smtp.gmail.com:587     auth
action "relay_booking"        relay tls host smtp://booking@smtp.gmail.com:587        auth
action "relay_password_reset" relay tls host smtp://password_reset@smtp.gmail.com:587 auth

match from local mail-from "booking@example.com"        for any action "relay_booking"
match from local mail-from "password-reset@example.com" for any action "relay_password_reset"
match from local mail-from "www-data"                   for any action "relay_monitoring"
match from local mail-from "root"                       for any action "relay_monitoring"
match from local mail-from "prometheus-alertmanager"    for any action "relay_monitoring"
match from local mail-from "monitoring@example.com"     for any action "relay_monitoring"

match from any reject
# OR relay all other emails via monitoring (potentially dangerous)
#match from any for any action "relay_monitoring"
```

and `/etc/smtpd/tables/auth_secrets`:

```
# SMTP account for booking confirmation emails
webapp_booking booking@example.com:very-secure-password

# SMTP account for password reset emails
webapp_pw_reset password-reset@example.com:super-secure-password

# SMTP account for all other emails
monitoring monitoring@example.com:extremely-secret-password
```

That's all. Super easy to understand.